# How to dispatch touch events to children after consuming

Tags: android

The layout is like:

[image]

View 1 is a self-defined layout `FlipperLayout`, and View 2 is a extended ListView `PinnedHeaderListView` which I want to add a "pull to refresh" function. View 1 need to listen to touch event in order to flip left or right. View 2 also need the touch event. And problem is that if View 1 consumed the touch event, View 2 can't get it.

**How Can I dispatch the event to View 2 even after View 1 consumed it?**

Comment: what kind of events do you want to dispatch to view2?

Comment: @pskink I want to listen to a gesture so basically I need ACTION_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE, ACTION_UP

Comment: ok but why the events that occured in view1 have to be passsed to view2?

Comment: @pskink Cuz View 1 contains View 2

Comment: view1 is a custom layout, right? override its onInterceptTouchEvent mwthod and return false there

Comment: @pskink Plz refer to my comments of Chen's answer, I think this doesn't work fine.

Comment: you think or you didnt override onInterceptTouchEvent ? just do it it will take you one minute

Comment: @zoujyjs did you find a solution? I'm in a similar situation...

Answer (score 1):

consider the following custom layout:

```
class FlingLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private GestureDetector mDetector;

    public FlingLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        OnGestureListener listener = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFling vx: " + velocityX + ", vy: " + velocityY);
                if (Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY)) {
                    String text = (velocityX > 0? "left to right" : "right to left") + " fling";
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        };
        mDetector = new GestureDetector(context, listener);
        setBackgroundColor(0xaaff0000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onTouchEvent " + event);
        // handle own events (initiated in red area)
        mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent " + ev);
        // handle child events
        // note: if you horizontally fling over button its onClick() is not performed
        return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

and its usage in your Activity:

```
ViewGroup ll = new FlingLinearLayout(this);
Button b;
OnClickListener l = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Button b = (Button) v;
        Log.d(TAG, "onClick " + b.getText());
    }
};
b = new Button(this);
b.setText("first");
b.setOnClickListener(l);
ll.addView(b);
b = new Button(this);
b.setText("second");
b.setOnClickListener(l);
ll.addView(b);
b = new Button(this);
b.setText("third");
b.setOnClickListener(l);
ll.addView(b);
setContentView(ll);
```

Comment: good point at return mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev); in onInterceptTouchEvent

Answer (score 0):

The touch event returns a boolean specifying if event was consumed or not, just return false, and event will continue to tunnel to children views

Comment: No, it's only true for the first event ACTION_DOWN. The following ACTION_MOVE and ACTION_UP will directly dispatch to the one that returns true(in this case, it should be view 2). So bacically, if you just return false in the parent, you can capture ACTION_DOWN in parent and child view. But you can't capture others in parent, but only in child view 2. This is where the problem is.