# Handling motion event many times

Tags: android

I have two Views: a child view and a parent view (child is part of the parent view); each of the Views has its own onTouchListener. I would like each view to handle its own onInterceptTouchEvent.  Right now; however, the child view's onTouchListener never receives any events.  They are all being sent to the parent view's listener.  How can I make sure the child view receives its own events?

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    //Log.d(TAG, "onInterceptTouchEvent " + ev);
    // handle child events
    // note: if you horizontally fling over button its onClick() is not performed


        MotionEvent ss  = MotionEvent.obtain(ev);
        globalVariabels.currentGallery.onTouchEvent(ss);
        int bounds[] = {0,0};
        globalVariabels.currentGallery.getLocationOnScreen(bounds);
        int height = globalVariabels.currentGallery.getHeight() + bounds[0];
        int width = globalVariabels.currentGallery.getWidth() + bounds[1];
        TouchDelegate delegate = new TouchDelegate(new Rect(0, 0, 2000, 2000), globalVariabels.currentGallery); 
         setTouchDelegate(delegate);
        switch (ev.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                mIgnore = false;
                Log.e("ooo", "oo");
                Log.e("X:","" + ev.getX());
                Log.e("Y:","" + ev.getY());
                mNeedToRebase = true;
                mInitialX = ev.getX();
                mInitialY = ev.getY();
                return false ;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                if (!mIgnore) {
                    Log.e("22", "22");
                    float deltaX = Math.abs(ev.getX() - mInitialX);
                    float deltaY = Math.abs(ev.getY() - mInitialY);
                    mIgnore = deltaX < deltaY;
                    super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
                    return !mIgnore;
                }
                return false;
            }
            default: {
                return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: and your problem is ...?

Comment: The event is handle by the parent when I try to slide the child.

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979285/how-to-dispatch-touch-events-to-children-after-consuming

Comment: But I have another onInterceptTouchEvent

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: When I place your code in my custom gallery the gallery won`t switch.

Comment: I use Gallery instead LinearLayout

Comment: it should work with any parent/child views

Comment: But I dont need onClick.I need onTouch.I have a gallery inside a gallery and the outer gallery overrides the onTouch event of the inner gallery.

Comment: you cannot have a gallery inside another gallery, it will not work

Comment: Well it is not a galleri inside gallery.It is gallery inside of something like horizontal scroll view.(Swipe view) http://jasonfry.co.uk/blog/android-swipeview-update/

Comment: Can you post the code where you add the listeners?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `dispatchTouchEvent` instead of `onInterceptTouchEvent`. I had faced some problems with it, since on some devices (on Samsungs, to be more precise) it may work not as expected. And dispatching is really simplier.

Idea is that you'll override `dispatchTouchEvent`, call super and handle your motion events. Here is an example:

```
@Override
protected boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    //perform your on-touch behaviour

    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);    //child's onTouchListener will be triggered
}
```